# Not able to stop the service.?

Tags: android

Here is my code:

```
package com.callplus;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class AudioRecordTest extends Service {
    private static String TAG = "AudioRecordTest";
    private static String FileName = null;
    private MediaRecorder Recorder = null;
    public static String callerName, date, path,number;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Log.d(TAG, "I am in Oncreate");
        DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
        db.open(SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
        db.getPath();
        path = db.audioPath;
        db.close();

        final TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener() {
            public void onCallStateChanged(final int state,
                    final String incomingNumber) {
                try {
                    switch (state) {
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                        if (Recorder != null) {
                            Recorder.release();
                            Recorder.stop();
                        }
                        Log.d("TestActivity", "Call is idle.");
                        actionStop(getApplicationContext());
                        break;
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                        Log.d("TestActivity", "Call connected");
                        startRecording();
                        break;
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;

                    }
                } finally {

                }
            }
        }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        stopSelf();

    }
    public static void actionStop(Context ctx) 
    {
    Intent i = new Intent(ctx, AudioRecordTest.class);
    Log.d(TAG, "I am in ActionStop");
//  i.setAction(ACTION_STOP);
    ctx.startService(i);
    }
}
```

I want to stop the service when call idle.

Comment: its not workng still.what should i do? and in ACTION_STOP.It is saying that ACTION_STOP can not b resolved.

Answer (score 1):

hi in actionStop method instead of stopService method call you have called startService method again.

```
ctx.stopService(i);
```

Use the above line instead of that and tel the response